# Who is www.theitcrib.com and what do they do?

Tags: scam

I paid $80 on Aug 23 for [what I thought was] a one-year license for Windows tech support to theitcrib.com/my-account. But I suspect I have been scammed.

It started with a phone call saying, in effect, that my Windows computer has some problems. ... May we clean up your computer up for you. Your performance will then be much better... got me to use a remote desktop app (lost it when I tried to access it on my desktop. It was shown in a yellow triangle. I think it was "GotoMyPC" but maybe LogMeIn?

Then came the request for payment. I refused. We argued briefly... 
I was in a bit of a panic at the time so I didn't stop to think carefully... I observed stuff being done sporadically for the next 3 hours, then we parted ways.

I received an email receipt but, on inspection, I think it just indicates I paid for 2 copies of wordpress theme 13floor.

Your attention is appreciated. I'd like to not [have to] do this ever again.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. It looks like you were a target of a PC support scam. You will need to deal with your credit card company and your local police.

Comment: If you let someone gain access to your computer, you don't know what they did, so you should nuke-from-orbit and do a clean install.

Comment: @schroeder I think the question is basically "what kind of scam is this?" And "This is a technical support scam (which may be used to do X, Y, and Z)" seems like a good answer. And with this keyword alone, OP could already find out more on their own.

Comment: @tim as this is a Q&A site, it is important that we (and the OP) are clear on what the question actually is so that we don't end up providing multiple tangents on possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

They got access to your computer which means they could see what you typed and access your files - from there they got your credit card numbe and purchased a few themes (possibly for a new scam site they're setting up). Then, either they moved on or the bank declined further payments because they didn't fit into your usual spending patterns to limit the risk of fraud (and they were right).

Get in touch with your bank to completely cancel the card and issue a chargeback on the fraudulent payments, reinstall the machine from scratch (using install media created from another, clean machine), change all your passwords/private keys/etc, and consider yourself lucky they were amateurs and only managed to spend a few dozen bucks on a theme. Usually it's much worse than that.

Answer (score 0):

A whois search of theitcrib.com shows it was registered in February 2016 and is hosted on godaddy.com, so the site is pretty new. There's no way to tell from this if you were scammed or not, but if you do not receive the services you request from a business, you can dispute the charge with your credit card company.

A big concern is that someone you don't know remotely connected to your system, monitor it for any strange outgoing traffic using the "netstat -antup" command.

Comment: Windows `netstat` doesn't have `u`, `t` is useless, and `p` doesn't do anything you want. `-ano` (or elevated `-anb`) might help if you did it continuously all the time your computer is on _and_ the villains didn't alter anything in your network stack or kernel -- which given the rather vague question isn't a very safe bet.

Comment: I don't think the solution here is to try to monitor suspisious activity. Just treat the computer as infected, and nuke from orbit.